# empty img src while scraping website using requests-html python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

When I was using Beautifulsoup and requests module to scrape the `img`'s `src`, all the `img`
s `src` are empty so then I'm assuming that the `src` value is generated by JavaScript. Hence, I tried to use the requests_html module instead. However, when I trying to scrape the same information after the response is rendered, only two of the `img` 's `src` has value and the rest are empty but the problem is that when I checked it on the website using developer tools, it seems that the other `img`'s src should have a value. May I know what is the problem here?

## code for bs4 and requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

biliweb = requests.get('https://www.bilibili.com/ranking/bangumi/13/0/3').text

bilisoup = BeautifulSoup(biliweb,'lxml')

for item in bilisoup.find_all('div',class_='lazy-img'):
    
    image_html = item.find('img')
    print(image_html)
```

## code for requets_html

```
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

biliweb =  session.get('https://www.bilibili.com/ranking/bangumi/13/0/3')
biliweb.html.render() 


for item in biliweb.html.find('.lazy-img.cover > img'):
    print(item.html)
```

## I will only show the first five results because the list is quite lengthy

> With Beautifulsoup and requests

<img alt="Re：从零开始的异世界生活 第二季" src=""/>
<img alt="刀剑神域 爱丽丝篇 异界战争 -终章-" src=""/>
<img alt="没落要塞 / DECA-DENCE" src=""/>
<img alt="某科学的超电磁炮T" src=""/> 
<img alt="宇崎学妹想要玩！" src=""/>

> With requests_html

<img alt="Re：从零开始的异世界生活 第二季" src="https://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/f2425cbdb07cc93bd0d3ba1c0099bfe78f5dc58a.png@90w_120h.webp"/> 
<img alt="刀剑神域 爱丽丝篇 异界战争 -终章-" src="https://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/54d9ca94ca84225934e0108417c2a1cc16be38fb.png@90w_120h.webp"/> 
<img alt="没落要塞 / DECA-DENCE" src=""/>
<img alt="某科学的超电磁炮T" src=""/> 
<img alt="宇崎学妹想要玩！" src=""/>

Answer (score 0):

All the data is stored in a javascript variable called `__INITIAL_STATE__`.

The following script saves the data in a json file. Once you have this, you can easily download the images.

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.bilibili.com/ranking/bangumi/13/0/3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

script = None
for s in soup.find_all("script"):
    if "__INITIAL_STATE__" in s.text:
        script = s.get_text(strip=True)
        break

data = json.loads(script[script.index('{'):script.index('function')-2])

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'rankList': [{'badge': '会员抢先', 'badge_info': {'bg_color': '#FB7299', 'bg_color_night': '#BB5B76', 'text': '会员抢先'}, 'badge_type': 0, 'copyright': 'bilibili', 'cover': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/f2425cbdb07cc93bd0d3ba1c0099bfe78f5dc58a.png', 'new_ep': {'cover': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/archive/2f5bf4840747fc7c09932d2793e96a178cd05905.jpg', 'index_show': '更新至第5话'}, 'pts': 1903981, 'rank': 1, 'season_id': 33802, 'stat': {'danmaku': 814356, 'follow': 7135303, 'series_follow': 7267882, 'view': 33685387}, 'title': 'Re：从零开始的异世界生活 第二季', 'url': 'https://www.bilibili.com/bangumi/play/ss33802', 'pic': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/f2425cbdb07cc93bd0d3ba1c0099bfe78f5dc58a.png', 'play': 33685387, 'video_review': 814356}, {'badge': '会员抢先', 'badge_info': {'bg_color': '#FB7299', 'bg_color_night': '#BB5B76', 'text': '会员抢先'}, 'badge_type': 0, 'copyright': 'bilibili', 'cover': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/54d9ca94ca84225934e0108417c2a1cc16be38fb.png', 'new_ep': {'cover': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/archive/a772451f1f031ee1a3b78e31e4fb0b851517817f.jpg', 'index_show': '更新至第16话'}, 'pts': 483317, 'rank': 2, 'season_id': 32781, 'stat': {'danmaku': 514174, 'follow': 6195736, 'series_follow': 6733547, 'view': 36351270}, 'title': '刀剑神域 爱丽丝篇 异界战争 -终章-', 'url': 'https://www.bilibili.com/bangumi/play/ss32781', 'pic': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/54d9ca94ca84225934e0108417c2a1cc16be38fb.png', 'play': 36351270, 'video_review': 514174}, {'badge': '会员抢先', 'badge_info': {'bg_color': '#FB7299', 'bg_color_night': '#BB5B76', 'text': '会员抢先'}, 'badge_type': 0, 'copyright': 'bilibili', 'cover': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/bangumi/image/d5d7441c20614dc5ddc69f333f1906a09eddcee2.png', 'new_ep': {'cover': 'http://i0.hdslb.com/bfs/archive/fe191e9ffa2422103bffcd8615446f5885074c0b.jpg', 'index_show': '更新至第5话'}, 'pts': 455170, 'rank': 3, 'season_id': 33803, 'stat': ....
...
...
...
```

Comment: May I ask what is the reason for only 2 of the src show up but not all?

Comment: @Newbie The website loads the data via javascript.